# How to access variable of type google.protobuf.Timestamp in python

Tags: python, timestamp, grpc

I need to access the variable of type google.protobuff.Timestamp to get todays date and I am unable to access it using FromDateTime?

Answer (score 1):

See [here](https://developers.google.com/protocol-buffers/docs/reference/python-generated#timestamp) including an example using `FromDateTime`

Comment: google.protobuf.Int32Value requestId----- I have requestId of type Int32Value? How should I acess it in pyscript cause I am unable to directly assign requestId= 30?